# Append data or values to csv file Column wise in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, append, printf

suppose i have a .csv file And it has the values as follows:

```
 A  23 45

 B  69 84

 C  48 78

 D  12 34
```

so it has two columns. Now what i need to do is to add values staring from the 3rd column with out deleting the values in the 1st and 2nd columns..

i tried z code

```
fileID = fopen('exp.csv','A');

fprintf(fileID,' %12.4f\n',D);

fclose(fileID);
```

But the issue is that this is added all in one column like:

```
23 

69 

48 

12 

......
45 

84

75

38
```

How can i do this...??

Comment: I think i understand what you're asking but as formulated the question is confusing. You write: "so it has two columns" but I see 3 columns at the very top!

Answer (score 2):

Use the csvread / csvwrite functions to load in the existing file, append a column, and write the new data.

```
data = csvread('exp.csv');
toadd = (1:4)';
newdata = [data toadd];
csvwrite('out.csv', newdata);
```